# Python - Creating classes & calculation methods with dataframe inputs

Tags: python, object

I need to build classes and methods for different calculation steps:

I got a dataframe with numerical columns A,B,C.

I want the class to initialize the columns of the dataframe as inputs so I can call following methods:

Method1:
sum(A)

Method2:
sum(A)*B

How do you do that in Python?

I know it is a really general question, but I only came across really abstract OOP tutorials. I need it more specific on calculations & finance.
A good source to some tutorial would also help.

Thanks,

KS

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "initializ[ing] the columns"? Do you want to ensure the frame has the A and B columns defined? Do you want to populate it with garbage data?

Comment: So I got a dataframe called df which is already populated with numerical data in columns df["A"] and df["B"]. Now one method 1 should for example do df["A"].sum() and method 2 should df["A"].sum() *df["B]. Is this clearer?

Comment: So you don't actually want to modify the df, you just want to pass it to your methods as an input parameter?

Comment: Yes, excactly. Inputs should be numeric columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class MyCalculator:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def m1(self):
        return self.df['A'].sum()

    def m2(self):
        # return np.multiply(self.m1(), self.df['B']).values
        return np.multiply(self.m1(), self.df['B']).values.reshape(-1, 1)


d = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
}


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print(f'frame:\n {df}')

    b = MyCalculator(df)
    print(f'method 1:\n {b.m1()}')
    print(f'method 2:\n {b.m2()}')


# start
main()
```

Output:

```
frame:
    A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
method 1:
 6
method 2:
 [[24]
 [30]
 [36]]
```